# Overheating issue with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I recently set up a dual boot with windows 10/ubuntu 16.04. It works fine on windows, but there is an overheating issue on ubuntu. I am running it on a HP Elite pc, 4gb ddr2 ram and an nVidia Geforce 9100

Comment: Are you sure it's not also overheating on Windows? I had this same problem on an old Acer laptop. I found it was the laptop, not the OS.

Comment: What happens if you install Oracle Virtualbox and install an Ubuntu 16.04 VM in that on the Windows partition? Does it overheat when going fullscreen on that, as well? Not that I have an answer here, but it may present more facts.